# what does "to walk at grade" mean?

Tags: nouns, idioms, vocabulary

"John was walking at grade and slipped on a patch of ice. When John slipped he did not fall to grade as he caught himself with his right hand [...]"

Does "at grade" mean "on an uneven/inclined surface", or "on a slope" ?

Comment: What is the context for the text? *[At-grade](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/at-grade)* is a technical term and not commonly used by people who are not road engineers, insurance adjusters, or other professionals.

Comment: What Choster said. OED has this definition 11: *Of a surface: Degree of altitude; level. **rare. at grade (U.S.): on the same level.*** I wasn't really familiar with this "technical/engineering" usage, but after a pretty fruitless search in Google Books for ***fall/fell to grade***, I'm far from convinced OP's *second* instance is idiomatically acceptable in *any* context.

Comment: @choster - your're right, this is a modified excerpt from a construction injury report

Comment: @choster It looks very much to me as if that is the intended meaning, rather than MrWonderful's answer. I would make it an answer.

Comment: 'Grade crossing' is the US equivalent of 'level crossing' in the UK.

Comment: Normal speech in USA: *John was walking on the ground and slipped on a patch of ice. When John slipped he did not fall to the ground as he caught himself with his right hand.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *John was walking at grade and slipped on a patch of ice. When John slipped he did not fall to grade as he caught himself with his right
>   hand [...]*

In construction, *[grade](http://www.dictionaryofconstruction.com/definition/grade.html)* has several potential meanings:

> grade
>
> Definitions (8)
>
> 1. The surface or level of the ground.
> 2. A classification of quality as, for instance, in lumber.
> 3. The existing or proposed ground level or elevation on a building site or around a building.
> 4. The slope or rate of incline or decline of a road, expressed as a percent.
> 5. A designation of a subfloor, either above grade, on grade, or below grade.
> 6. In plumbing, the slope of installed pipe, expressed in the fall in inches per foot length of pipe.
> 7. The classification of the durability of brick.
> 8. Any surface prepared to accept paving, conduit, or rails.
>
> *dictionaryofconstruction.com*

The expressions *walking at grade* and *fall to grade*, clearly eliminate five definitions, and leave three possibilities to choose from:

> grade
>
> Definitions (8)
>
> 1. The surface or level of the ground.
> 2. The existing or proposed ground level or elevation on a building site or around a building.
> 3. Any surface prepared to accept paving, conduit, or rails.

All three of the remaining definitions are consistent with the the ODO definition of *[at grade](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/at-grade?q=at%20grade)*:

> *North American* On the **same** level:
>
> Emphasis mine

On a construction site, the **default** meaning of grade is "existing ground level", unless otherwise specified. The most likely interpretation is:

> *John was walking at **ground** level and slipped on a patch of ice. When John slipped he did not fall to **ground** level as he caught
>   himself with his right hand.*

If the larger context provides information specifying another definition of  *grade*, it is interpreted:

> *John was walking at a **specified** level and slipped on a patch of ice. When John slipped he did not fall to the **specified** level as
>   he caught himself with his right hand.*

We know from this account that John fell **less** than his own height at or near ground level.